# Creating an array filled with array-variables in cshell

Tags: arrays, csh

I want to populate in array in chsell such that each index in the array will be an array itself. That is, if I ran

```
set a = ( `seq 1 2 10` )
set b = ( `seq 2 2 10` )
set array = ( $a $b )
echo $array[2]
```

then the return would be 2 4 6 8 10 (which is $b) instead of 3 (which is $a[2]).

Ultimately I could get away with declaring a bunch of variables, but it will make my code a mess. This would be similar to a cell in Matlab if that helps clarify the end result. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Csh doesn't have arrays, it only has lists of words, and is only a very limited programming language.

Given your constraints for a maintainable "clean" way of doing this in csh, the answer is **no there is no solution**.

This is very easy in a language such as Perl, which is designed for situations like this where the standard shells and UNIX utilities run out of steam.

Comment: Luckily, I no longer work with the people who required Csh for scripting. Thanks for enlightening me to the exact limitations in this situation, though!