# How to grep a pattern in an array using CSH script

Tags: csh

I am working in CSH script and i am new to this script. My requirement is to grep a pattern in an array. I am able to get the same using bash but unable in CSH. Could you please help me this.

Bash programmin

```
        a = (arun kumar input output pin port)
        if [[ "${a[*]}" =~ "varun" ]]; then
               echo "Match found"
        fi
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: grep is a program

Comment: so what is equivalent to above code in CSH

Comment: perhaps use grep?

Comment: I used grep but it is excepting filename instead of array. i have tried below one

Comment: grep "arun" $a.

Comment: you can use a pipe - `echo input | grep "pattern"`

Comment: Can we use if condition like the below :   if (`echo $a | grep varun`)

Comment: Yes, you can. You probably want `echo ${var[@]}`

Comment: No it didn`t work. i used if (echo ${a[@]}) and if (echo ${a[*]}) both showing if expression syntax

Comment: It make sense as that is not proper if syntax. Also [c shell doesn't seem to support arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290835/creating-an-array-filled-with-array-variables-in-cshell), how are you even getting this far?

Comment: csh has arrays @php_nub_qq; they're just called "lists" and don't allow nesting. Arguably these are not "true" arrays, but for the purpose of this question it's "close enough". Also things like `${var[@]}` isn't supported in csh; you can just do `"$var"` for the same effect as you would get in bash. To be honest, it's better if you would refrain from commenting if you're not familiar with the involved language/tech, as it's not helpful at all.

Comment: If you are new to `csh` you should seriously consider walking away from it.  Quickly.  The only reason to use `csh` is if you have 10 years experience using it and don't want to abandon that time investment, or if you are working on a legacy code base.  Even then, it's probably worthwhile.  The language is inherently ambiguous, and learning it will not serve you well. Learn a Bourne variant instead.

Comment: I appreciate you're trying to be helpful @php_nub_qq, but a lot of what you said was wrong.

Comment: @MartinTournoij could you be more specific, apart from addressing arrays, what else that I said was wrong?

Answer (score 1):

csh has a very different syntax from Bourne shells such as bash; specifically:

- You need to use `set` to assign variables, so:

  ```
    a = (arun kumar input output pin port)
  ```

  won't work, you need to use:

  ```
  set a = (arun kumar input output pin port)
  ```
- The syntax for `if` is `if ( .. ) then [..] endif`, rather then `if [[ .. ]]; then [..] fi`.

There are *many* other differences too. If you must use csh, then it's best to just forget about the Bourne shell and start from zero.

---

Anyway, what you want to do is "check if a word appears in a list". Your bash example isn't quite correct either, since it just converts the array to a string and then checks if a pattern occurs with `=~`. This works fine for some cases, but consider what would happen if you want to check if the word "out" appears in your list: it would match `output`.

One way to do this would be to use:

```
set a = (arun kumar input output pin port)
if ( " $a " =~ *" varun "* ) then
        echo "Match found"
endif
```

Lists are automatically converted to a string. We surround this in spaces so that it only checks for the full word `varun`, rather than anything containing `varun` to fix the issue mentioned above.

I adapted the above [from this answer on the Unix & Linux site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/537261/33645) (I don't use csh that often these days, so I couldn't remember what the best way to do it was), which I found [with this search](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=tcsh+check+if+word+appears+in+list&ia=web).

---

As an aside, csh is a very awkward language with many limitations and problems. I would highly recommend avoiding it and using bash (or even better: zsh) if you're able to.